# Deepin 15.5 Linux Sudo and su

Tags: linux, sudo, su, deepin

I have a deepin linux (debian based) installed on my notebook 3 days ago and I'm trying to use sudo like `sudo apt-get install [somethings]` and I get this error:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin "sudoers_policy"
sudo: unable to load /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so: file too short
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

After that I try to use `su` and type password then I get:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

Comment: which password are you using for su?

Comment: That password was set in installing

Comment: When I used tools like Deepin Package Manager, that accepted my password.

Comment: I try to open termianl as admin with UI and I can change root password with passwd and I can set new password but sudo error Still remains

Answer (score 2):

I try to open terminal as admin with UI and I can change root password with passwd and I can set new password after than I remove sudo and reinstalled it.

It works now.

Comment: It looks like the `/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so` file was truncated or otherwise damaged, and removing & reinstalling the `sudo` package fixed it.